# Why does it open command prompt when i excute start hurry.bat?

Tags: batch-file, dos

This is about the START command in batch-files.

```
 start  notepad \\ opens the notepad but not the command prompt
 start  www.google.com   \\ opens the google.com but not the command prompt 
 start  hurry.bat\\ starts executing the batch file but opens the command prompt
```

Why so? Any reason ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notepad.exe` is a graphic user inteface (GUI) program: it interacts with the user in GUI and doesn't need the console window (command prompt).

`www.google.com` is interpreted as an internet address, and in order to process it (open the corresponging internet page) Windows calls your default browser, which is a GUI program too, like `notepad`, so, again, no command prompt needed.

Now, a batch file is merely a text file containg a set of commands, a script. It cannot execute by itself and needs a program to interprete the commands. `CMD.EXE` (the 'command prompt') is exactly the program that does that job.