# Problem with the start /wait command 

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd, dos

```
            @echo off
            start /wait notepad
            start worpad
```

This is the code i have written in a batch file. My aim  is to stop the batch file execution till the notepad application gets closed. Its working perfect  but the thing is, Its displaying the command prompt also .Its opening the command prompt when i execute

```
     start /wait notepad in my batch file.
```

The command prompt gets closed when i close my notepad. But i dont want the command prompt.How do i make that. I even tried these

```
    cmd /c start /wait notepad
```

even the above command is not working. How do i make it.How do i open only notepad without the command prompt and wait till it is closed ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this batch file? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just i want to gain some knowledge over the dos commands. Im learning how they really make our task easier. Thank you

Comment: The purpose of it , Its some where i have to use in my gaming program .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my answer to [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688738/why-does-it-open-command-prompt-when-i-excute-start-hurry-bat), the command prompt window is there because it is *the* tool that processes the batch file. The command prompt window is the working window of the `CMD.EXE` program, just like Notepad's working window is the one where you are editing text files. Typically, running a program with its working window hidden is a non-trivial task, unless the program has a pre-defined mode of running with the hidden window. As it happens, `CMD` does *not* have such a mode.

However, there is a way of starting a program with its window *minimised*. You only need to create a shortcut to your program (it can be a batch file too), then open the shortcut's properties, and on the Shortcut tab, set the Run property to `Minimized`. To make it clearer, here's an illustration:

[image]

Comment: Should i need to install foxit software? is there no way tp make it without using the above software ?

Comment: @niko: No, you don't need to install Foxit. I had to use a random shortcut's Properties dialog, because Windows on my computer is localised and I thought it would be more helpful if I used an English version of the dialog. I only intended to show you which option controls the program's state at its startup.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can just use the

```
ping localhost -n ( your time in second ) >nul
```

So your code will be like this

@echo off

start notepad

```
ping localhost -n ( your time in second ) >nul
```

start worpad