# batch file: hide console when using start /wait

Tags: file, batch-file, console, wait

```
@echo off
start /wait notepad.exe somefile.txt
if exist somefile.txt echo it exists.
```

this will display the normal console screen as well as notepad until notepad is closed. i don't want the console screen to appear; notepad must have focus; the 'if exist' line must not run until notepad is closed. the script is run from 'total commander' but running it from 'start/run' returns same results. the second line of code is irrelevant for this example.

cmd.exe /k does same thing.

internal batch commands only.
thanks!

win 7 64 bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with the start /wait command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746696/problem-with-the-start-wait-command)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Script Host to run your batch file. For example, create the file "startmybatch.vbs" with the following content:

```
Set ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd = "c:\mypath\mybatch.bat"
ret = ws.Run(cmd, 0, True)
Set ws = Nothing
```

then run "startmybatch.vbs" directly, or using "wscript startmybatch.vbs". At least on XP this works (console window is not visible). I think this will work on all Windows versions >= Win98.